# Join two datasets in Visual Studio Report Services

Tags: .net, sql, ms-access, reporting-services

I'm looking to join an access database to a different access database based on a common field. Any way to do this in a sql query?

```
accessdatabase1.commonfield to  accessdatabase2.commonfield
```

Comment: what programming language you are using?

Comment: im working in visual studio, just looking for a simple solution in SQL in the query if possible

Comment: What's the context here? Where are the data coming from? What are you trying to do with the combined data? As it stands, your question is too general to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

from your comment, you have mentioned that you want to do this on `SQL`,

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    tableA a
        INNER JOIN tableB b
           ON a.commonfield = b.commonfield
```

- [Visual Representation of Join](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: I get the following errors                                       ERROR [42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot find the input table or query 'DCS_Fact'.  Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly.                                                                                                                               OR                                                                   ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Could not find file 'C:\Windows\system32\dcsfact.mdb'.